# Informix error: unable to load locale categories

Tags: informix

I got the error "unable to load locale categories" when I tried to change my `DB_LOCALE` to Arabic (ar_ae.8859-6).
Also, I check my `INFORMIXDIR` env. variable.
My current `DB_LOCALE` is `EN_US.8859-1` which I got after installation.
I check my gls folder for `ar_ae` code set but I didn't find it.
I'm using trial Informix version.

Where I could download `ar_ae` locale, or is it not possible for the trial version?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to download the ILS (International Language Supplement) if the `ar_ae.8859-6` locale is not supplied with the base product — and I don't see it with a default installation on Mac OS X.

A Google search on 'ibm informix ils international language supplement' seems to come up with good hits.  Make sure you get the ILS for your version of Informix.

For example:

- [README for IBM Informix International Language Supplement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.relnotes.doc/notes/ils_readme_350mc7/ils_readme.html)

You may need to contact IBM/Informix Technical Support, or otherwise search for the download on the IBM web site (roughly where you download other Informix products).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will write to IBM support.